# Logstash MySQL JDBC LoadError: no such file to load -- <file-path>

Tags: docker, rubygems, docker-compose, logstash-configuration, logstash-jdbc

I want to build Docker-ELK from [this repository](https://github.com/edceo/docker-elk).

This is my logstash.conf file

```
input {
  jdbc {
    jdbc_driver_library => "/home/edsoft/IdeaProjects/docker-elk/resources/mysql-connector-java-5.1.36-bin.jar"
        jdbc_driver_class => "com.mysql.jdbc.Driver"
        jdbc_connection_string => "jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/yazilimokulu"
        jdbc_user => "root"
        jdbc_password => "1"
        schedule => "* * * * *"
        statement => "select * from posts"
    }
    tcp {
        port => 5000
    }
}

## Add your filters / logstash plugins configuration here

output {
    elasticsearch {
        hosts => ["elasticsearch:9200"]
        index => "posts"
        document_type => "post"
        document_id => "%{id}" ## must be lower case
    }
}
```

I run docker with docker-compose. Kibana and ElasticSearch start successfully but Logstash throw error

```
LoadError: no such file to load -- /home/edsoft/IdeaProjects/docker-elk/resources/mysql-connector-java-5.1.36-bin
logstash_1       |                   require at org/jruby/RubyKernel.java:1040
logstash_1       |                   require at /usr/share/logstash/vendor/bundle/jruby/1.9/gems/polyglot-0.3.5/lib/polyglot.rb:65
logstash_1       |              load_drivers at /usr/share/logstash/vendor/bundle/jruby/1.9/gems/logstash-input-jdbc-4.1.3/lib/logstash/plugin_mixins/jdbc.rb:134
logstash_1       |                      each at org/jruby/RubyArray.java:1613
logstash_1       |              load_drivers at /usr/share/logstash/vendor/bundle/jruby/1.9/gems/logstash-input-jdbc-4.1.3/lib/logstash/plugin_mixins/jdbc.rb:132
logstash_1       |   prepare_jdbc_connection at /usr/share/logstash/vendor/bundle/jruby/1.9/gems/logstash-input-jdbc-4.1.3/lib/logstash/plugin_mixins/jdbc.rb:146
logstash_1       |                  register at /usr/share/logstash/vendor/bundle/jruby/1.9/gems/logstash-input-jdbc-4.1.3/lib/logstash/inputs/jdbc.rb:191
logstash_1       |           register_plugin at /usr/share/logstash/logstash-core/lib/logstash/pipeline.rb:282
logstash_1       |          register_plugins at /usr/share/logstash/logstash-core/lib/logstash/pipeline.rb:293
logstash_1       |                      each at org/jruby/RubyArray.java:1613
logstash_1       |          register_plugins at /usr/share/logstash/logstash-core/lib/logstash/pipeline.rb:293
logstash_1       |              start_inputs at /usr/share/logstash/logstash-core/lib/logstash/pipeline.rb:436
logstash_1       |             start_workers at /usr/share/logstash/logstash-core/lib/logstash/pipeline.rb:337
logstash_1       |                       run at /usr/share/logstash/logstash-core/lib/logstash/pipeline.rb:232
logstash_1       |            start_pipeline at /usr/share/logstash/logstash-core/lib/logstash/agent.rb:387
```

I write path ...bin.jar but error delete .jar from filename. I write ..bin.jar.jar error code is ..bin.jar but doesn't find the file.

Please help me

Thank you

Answer (score 1):

The path you set for the `jdbc_driver_library` parameter doesn't exist within your container. You have to include the library file inside your Docker image or mount it from your host when you run the Logstash container.